# subsetting raster data to obtain spatial polygon data frame

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I ran this line of code to produce a `Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` of the United States

```
states <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "United States", level = 1)
```

I would like to get a spatial polygon dataframe with just Illinois and Wisconsin and I used this line of code thinking it would work...

```
statesilwi <- states[states$NAME_1 == "Illinois" & states$NAME_1 == "Wisconsin",]
```

It did not work, I ended up with this with like no information
[image: oops]

How do I do correctly do this? I am new to this so any not-so-complex help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `|` instead of `&`: `statesilwi <- states[states$NAME_1 == "Illinois" | states$NAME_1 == "Wisconsin",]`